# Django: how to stay DRY using custom querysets with Q object?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the custom queryset example bellow, the `displayable` method uses a combination of `permanent` and `scheduled` method. It works, but as you can see, I'm repeating myself:

```
class ArticlesByCategoryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def permanent(self):
        return self.filter(is_permanent=True)

    def scheduled(self, service):
        return self.filter(scheduled_services__in=[service])

    def displayable(self, service):
        complex_query = Q(is_permanent=True) | Q(scheduled_services__in=[service])
        return self.filter(complex_query)
```

What is the correct syntax to use `Q()` and stay DRY? I didn't find such an example in Django documentation.
I tried something like that, but it raises a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`:

```
def displayable(self, service):
    complex_query = Q(self.permanent()) | Q(self.scheduled(service))
    return self.filter(complex_query)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querysets can be combined with bitwise `or` too:

```
class ArticlesByCategoryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def permanent(self):
        return self.filter(is_permanent=True)

    def scheduled(self, service):
        return self.filter(scheduled_services__in=[service])

    def displayable(self, service):
        return self.permanent() | self.scheduled(service)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works and it's simple. Do you know about the differences with the @Satendra solution?

Comment: I'd have to install Django 1.11 (we're still stuck with 1.10 ATM) and try out both solutions check the generated SQL, but I assume `Queryset.union()` would issue something like "SELECT xxx UNION SELECT yyy" where or'ing two querysets (or two Q objects) issues a single SELECT or'ing the WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [union() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.union) of queryset New in Django 1.11, It uses SQL’s UNION operator to combine the results of two or more QuerySets.

```
def displayable(self, service):
    qs1 = self.permanent()
    qs2 = self.scheduled(service)
    return qs1.union(qs2)
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the `all=True` argument.

**UPDATE**

Both are used to merge/combine querysets, `union()` is New in Django 1.11

Major difference is *union(*other_qs, all=False)* return model instances of the type of the first QuerySet even if the arguments are QuerySets of other models.

The union operator for QuerySets is `|` the pipe symbol, only works on querysets from the same model and before slicing it.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know about the differences with the @bruno desthuilliers  solution?

Comment: I mark the other answer as accepted because it's what I was looking for, but thanks a lot for the extra information about `union`, very interesting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could you store your Q objects in a method like so:

```
class ArticlesByCategoryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def objects(self, service=None):
        return {
            'permanent': {
                'is_permanent': True,
            },
            'scheduled': {
                'scheduled_services__in': [service],
            },
        }

    def permanent(self):
        return self.filter(**self.objects(service)['permanent'])

    def scheduled(self, service):
        return self.filter(**self.objects(service)['scheduled'])

    def displayable(self, service):
        complex_query = Q(**self.objects(service)['permanent']) | Q(**self.objects(service)['scheduled'])
        return self.filter(complex_query)
```